# downloading and using an image via $.ajax

Tags: jquery-mobile

I don,t know it its possible or not but I have an image on my server and I want to download and display in my jquery mobile app via $.ajax function.Here is the code I am using:

```
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: $url,
dataType: "jpeg",
async: true,
timeout: 90000,
success: function($data)
    {   
 console.log("success");

},
error: function()
   {
console.log("failure");
}


});
```

I am getting an error and not sure whether this is the right approach

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make much sense to download images with AJAX. You probably just need to set the `src` attribute of of an ìmg `element`:

```
<div id="example">Example</div>
<script>
  var url = 'http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-64-48-8.jpg'; // URL of the image
  $('#example').click(function() {
    $('<img>') // create a new image element
       .attr('src', url) // set src
       .appendTo(this);
  });
</script>​
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/zrbRM/